# Microsoft iot-devkit: while doing the translator tutorial, I get "sorry I can't hear you" error

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, iot-devkit

I'm doing the Microsoft iot-devkit tutorial with the MXChip az3166. Specifically I'm doing the translate tutorial that comes included in Visual Studio Code for the MXChip az3166.

This is the link to the tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-arduino-iot-devkit-az3166-translator

I've tried doing the whole tutorial twice from scratch and everytime I think i'm done, I go to test the result. When I press the B button to record it says "processing" then "uploading" then it returns a message "Sorry, I can't hear you" If I try pressing the B button again it gets stuck on the screen: "Release to send. max duration 1.5 sec".
The error message I get on Azure in the function log in the dev_kit_trnslator is:

```
2019-02-05T18:17:59.844 [Information] Executing 'devkit_translator' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=f1bbebf0-10d5-463e-922e-5c3249c35b0c)
2019-02-05T18:17:59.845 [Information] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2019-02-05T18:17:59.845 [Information] Source language: fr-FR
2019-02-05T18:17:59.921 [Error] Executed 'devkit_translator' (Failed, Id=f1bbebf0-10d5-463e-922e-5c3249c35b0c)

Runtime exception
```

Comment: Is there any other message under 'Runtime exception'? Could you add more code in Azure Functions to print more information?

Comment: Hi @renhel, thanks for your response. There are no more messages under Runtime exception. I don't have time currently, or in the foreseeable future to add debug cod e to my current code. I was hoping that someone might have encountered this and could offer their solution. Either way, Thank you.